# Python 3.5 convert a string to the type of a sha1 sum

Tags: python-3.x, sha, digest

I know how to get the sha1 from a string and then get the digest sha1 from it which is my goal. But now the problem is that I already have the sha1 (which comes from a file not a string) and want to get the digest sha1 from it (and base 64 encode it).

```
mysha1 = "FB9BA6614A6AEB7A040881E09A4B8211405831FF"
print(base64.b64encode(mysha1.digest()))
```

and this leads to

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'digest'
```

Comment: If you already have the SHA1, why are you trying to digest it again? Just send it: `base64.b64encode(mysha1)`

Comment: does this not make a difference?

Comment: Well, if you try to re-digest it, you'll end up sending the hash of your hash. Is that what you want?

Comment: @BingsF Your snippet doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice "Python 3.5" in the title. Re-tagged as python-3.x.

Comment: http://pythoncentral.io/hashing-strings-with-python/

Answer (score 6):

Example with digest and hexdigest:

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> d = hashlib.sha1(b'footext')
>>> d.digest()
b'f\xf9\x88gI\xfdQK\x8eM\xbd\x9e\x18(\xcf\x860"\xf1\xbf'
>>> d.hexdigest()
'66f9886749fd514b8e4dbd9e1828cf863022f1bf'
```

How to turn the hexdigest into the digest:

```
>>> bytes.fromhex(d.hexdigest())
b'f\xf9\x88gI\xfdQK\x8eM\xbd\x9e\x18(\xcf\x860"\xf1\xbf'
```

Comment: Sorry, but thats not what i wanted to know (i got this from searching already). All i want as simple as i can describe it is: input sha1 -> output digest sha1

Comment: No idea what you're talking about then. Better provide an example including the desired result. And *"input sha1 -> output digest sha1"* isn't simple but just cryptic gibberish.